# Intellisense для requirejs модулей в visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, requirejs, intellisense

А в 2017 поддержку _references.js выпилили и подсветка обычных js файлов работает только если подсунуть системе d.ts файл с описанием, а как быть с requirejs модулями? Не хочу писать на тайпскрипте, хочу на чистом яваскрипте - возвращаться в 2015 студию?